# How to render only three elements of a array with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code, i did want to render the first three. elements of a array with several elements.

How i do can do that ?
My code:

```js
function AllComponnent () {
  const arr = [1,2,3,4];
  const elementsPerPage = 3;
  const currentPage = 0;
  
  
  const itensOnPage = arr.map(() => <ul> {currentPage*elementsPerPage} </ul>
);
 
  return (
    <div>
      <input/>
  <button onClick={action}> Click Here </button> 
  <button onClick={action}> Test</button>
   <h1> {itensOnPage} </h1>

    </div>


)}

ReactDOM.render (
<AllComponnent/>,
document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Which three? First three, last three, random three.

Comment: Oh yes, first three. sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd probably want to try something like

`<h1>
  { 
    itemsOnPage.slice(
      currentPage * elementsToRender, 
      (currentPage + 1) * elementsToRender
    ) 
  }
</h1>`

Though it'd be best to utilize React state here. If you had a constructor in your component, what you could do is

```
constructor(props) {
  this.state = { currentPage: 0, elementsPerPage: 3 }
  this.itemsToRender = [...]
}

renderableItems() {
  return this.itemsToRender.slice(
    this.state.currentPage * this.state.elementsPerPage,
    (this.state.currentPage + 1) * this.state.elementsPerPage
  )
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      { 
        //... other HTML 
      }
      <h1>{ this.renderableItems() }</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

There are great resources to learn JSX from the guys that wrote React itself, like https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice

```
const itensOnPage = arr.slice(0, elementsPerPage)map(() => // do your logic );
```

Hope this works.